# How to link to my own library in gcc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

**Command to build executable:**
`g++ -I../include/redis -L../lib/redis redis.cpp -o redis -lhiredis`

**Description:**
I have `libhiredis.so` in `../lib/redis/`. And in `/usr/local/lib/hiredis13/`, there are `libhiredis.so` and `libhiredis.so.0.13`, this `libhiredis.so` is a symbol link to `libhiredis.so.0.13`.Then I `ldd redis`, here is the result:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd227f7000)  
libhiredis.so.0.13 => not found  
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7ebca0d000)  
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7ebc70b000)  
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7ebc4f5000)  
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ebc132000)  
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ebcd23000)
```

Gcc should link to `libhiredis.so` in `../lib/redis/`, am I right?

Comment: `libhiredis.so` in `../lib/redis/` is not a symbol link.

Comment: @GundolfGundelfinger Thank you.I rename `libhiredis.so` to `libhiredis.so.0.13` and make `libhiredis.so` a symbol link of `libhiredis.so.0.13`.Thant worked! :-)

Comment: DON'T RENAME -- create a symlink to the original. (or build with the proper name to begin with `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The original is `libhiredis.so` which is not a symlink, so I rename it and create a symlink to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your library has a `SONAME` (`libhiredis.so.0.13`) so the program records it instead of the name of the file. Then, in runtime, that `SONAME` is searched for in the usual directories.

Your library is in `/usr/local/lib/hiredis13/`, and that is not a usual directory. The solution is one of the following:

- Add the `/usr/local/lib/hiredis13` directory in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` and re-run `ldconfig`.
- Export the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/hiredis13` when running the program.
- Use the `-rpath` linker option.

Comment: The `-rpath` method is a good choice as it will embed the library path in the executable making it immune from updates/changes that reset or alter `ld.so.conf` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed, I prefer `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to others.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Personally, I prefer the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and a shell script that exports it and launches the binary.

Comment: Both have advantages and inconveniences.